# Storing returned result from sql query in the form of array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to store the result of SQL query in an array.I am not able to use that result,however i can print it using print_r() method of php and it is printing-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SNO] => 1
            [chartType] => pie
            [outputValues] => rural_total_m,urban_total_m
            [attributeId] => 10025
            [level] => india
        )
)
```

I want it to store in a variable or a file in the form of--

```
Array(      
       SNO => 1,
       chartType => pie,
       outputValues => rural_total_m,urban_total_m,
       attributeId => 10025,
       level => india
    )
```

I have tried few thing but nothing like i want till now! :(
Thank You!

Comment: Why do you even want to store it that way? Making it just harder to get the information back and save new value to it.

Comment: Because i have some work pending and that totally depends on the result returned by SQL query. If its not in that form i will have to start things from begining! And i have seen that the array can be of this form! So, is there any way that i can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not sure why you will need this type of things -- but technically it is not possible -- an array cannot have **2 keys with same name** / **same key twice**. So you can't do this.

### UPDATE:

In case of duplicate keys to be managed - you can do something like:

Store the query result in `$result`

```
   $result = array();
   $sql = mysql_query("... your sql ...");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {
      $result[] = $row;
   }
```

Say this is how the $result looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SNO] => 1
            [chartType] => pie
            [outputValues] => rural_total_m,urban_total_m
            [attributeId] => 10025
            [level] => india
        )
)
```

Now parse it following way (or you can do it any other way like foreach, map, etc.)

```
$output = array();
array_walk($result, function ($value, $key) use (&$output) {
    // here the $value is the single array you are looking for. 
    $output[] = $value;
});

print_r($output);
```

This will do.

Comment: i knew that, this duplicacy is going to be a prob! Anyways, what if i don't have duplicate keys?
Please see the Que again!

Comment: In that case you just do something like: merging the two arrays or joining them. See update in answer.

Comment: But the problem is in reading it from SQL query! How to do it from SQL query result?

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it! :)